# making an image within a card fill in the space

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I am making a website using react and reactstrap, I have a card containing an image, the card is a square and the image is a rectangle, i want the image to fill in the card in the same fashion as an image set to fill in the background of a screen (cropping the edges to fit, thus avoiding the image getting stretched).

I have tried setting the width to auto while the height is at 100%, but the image only ends up smaller than it's normal size but overflows from the card, and not centered.

```
<Row ClassName="posts">
  <Col>
    <Card style={{ height:"460px", width:"460px"}}>
      <a href="#"><img className="img-fluid" src={media_picture} width="auto" height="100%"/></a>
    </Card>
  </Col>
  <Col>
    <Card style={{ height:"460px", width:"460px"}}>
      <a href="#"><img className="img-fluid" src={media_picture} width="auto" height="100%"/></a>
    </Card>
  </Col>
</Row>
```

I want the resulting image to be contained in the card, centered and filled in like a background image.

Answer (score 1):

You might benefit from adding [Bootstrap from NPMJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap) to your project. You can then utilize the basic styles in the documentation.

All you would have to do is add `className="img-fluid"` to your `img`'s

```
<Row ClassName="posts">
  <Col>
    <Card style={{ height:"460px", width:"460px"}}>
      <a href="#"><img className="img-fluid" src={media_picture} width="auto" height="100%"/></a>
    </Card>
  </Col>
  <Col>
    <Card style={{ height:"460px", width:"460px"}}>
      <a href="#"><img className="img-fluid" src={media_picture} width="auto" height="100%"/></a>
    </Card>
  </Col>
</Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure that  not have any padding

```
padding:0
```

then make  position is absolute

```
height:'100%'
marginLeft:auto
marginRight:auto
display:'block'
```